# How to inject/lookup EJB from SevletContextListener in JBoss AS 6

Tags: jboss, ejb

I am facing stackoverflow error when I inject ejb using @EJB or JNDI lookup using InitialContext. Can anybody share kow to inject/lookup EJB from SevletContextListener in JBoss AS 6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lookup, you can do something similar to this

```
InitialContext ctx =new InitialContext();
EjbServiceInterface service= (EjbServiceInterface) ctx.lookup("java:global/earName/ejbJarName/EjbServiceInterfaceImpl!com.example.EjbServiceInterface");
```

In this example, EjbServiceInterface is a remote interface for EjbServiceInterfaceImpl, which implements the ejb service.

The jndi string depends on the place where you are doing the lookup.. For a local lookup, you don't have to specify earName and ejbJarName.. I recommend looking in your startup log, where it shows the jndi names available for your ejb, and then select the one you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the same method but got stackoverflow error. 17:12:33,614 ERROR [[/app]] Error configuring application listener of class com.app.web.CustomContextListener: java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12$6.run(VersionHelper12.java:182) [:1.7.0_07]
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.7.0_07]
 at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.getContextClassLoader(VersionHelper12.java:179) [:1.7.0_07]
 at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getFactory(ResourceManager.java:403) [:1.7.0_07]

Comment: When I checked log as you mentioned in the comment, the JNDI name was different. Issue got fixed when I used the following code:@EJB(mappedName="app/EventStreamBean/local-app.eventStream.EventStreamLocal")
    private EventStreamLocal eventStreamBean; Thanks!